# Ionic 6, How to notify children component that parent ion-modal presented, or how to keep focus in modal input

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic6

I need to set focus on an `input` of a child component of `ion-modal`,
opening the modal is stealing the focus from the child `input`.

my first solution was to add a focus on mounted in children
**parent**

```
const modal = await modalController.create({
    component: ChildrenCompWithInput,
});
modal.present();
```

**ChildrenCompWithInput**

```
<template>
    <ion-input ref="inputElementRef"></ion-input>
</template>
<script>
...
... 
mounted(){
   // this will not work, mounted happened before modal is finishing it's present, so the modal takes the focus
   (this.$refs.inputElementRef as InstanceType < typeof IonInput > ).$el.setFocus();
   setTimeout(()=>{
        // this will work, but it's a SHITTY solution, and prone to race conditions
        (this.$refs.inputElementRef as InstanceType < typeof IonInput > ).$el.setFocus();
   },500)
}
```

I am looking for a way to notify the children element that the parent modal finished loading.

I had played with the next idea, but couldn't find a way to talk with the children component

```
const modal = await modalController.create({
    component: ChildrenCompWithInput,
});
modal.present();

// best solution would be
modal.addEventListener("did-present",()=>{
   // this will not work because I couldn't find any way to make the modalController expose the children's instance. 
   modal.ChildrenCompWithInputInstance.callFocusMethod();   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution I found is working but unfortunately, it's an antipattern.
the solution is that the child component will listen to the parent `<ion-modal>` `'did-present'` event

(you might see it in the documentation as `didPresent` or `ionModalDidPresent` if you want to listen to ionic 6 event make sure to use `kebab-case` i.e. `ion-modal-did-present` at least this is the case with vueJs framework)

this is an antipattern because vueJs pattern (and generally when working with components) is the next:
**parent -> child**  communication - pass data through props, and call child methods directly.
**child -> parent**  communication - child emits an event, and the parent is listening to the event.

so child listening to parent events is not the best way to solve it...

but it works and solved my problem.
if one-day the Ionic team will expose the component instance to the modal instance, the correct answer might be changed.

**ChildrenCompWithInput**

```
<template>
        <ion-input ref="inputElementRef"></ion-input>
</template>
<script>
...
...

mounted(){
   // get the parent ion-modal 
   // and listen to did-present event
   this.$el.parentElement.closest("ion-modal").addEventListener("did-present",()=>{
      // focus on the input element
      (this.$refs.inputElementRef as InstanceType<typeof IonInput>).setFocus();
   })
}
```